# how to save images with metricam in c# console application

Tags: c#, console-application, webcam, picturebox, save-image

I am using this code to get images from my webcam, I guess its Metricam library

Anyone knows how to get images without using picturebox?

```
WebCam camera = new WebCam();
camera.Connect();
pictureBox1.Image = camera.GetBitmap();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\image1 " + ".Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Thanks bro :) I really appreciate your quick response on this. God bless you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pictureBox1.Image` is `Image` type. It can handle saving on its own. It does handle saving when used from `PictureBox` too, notice how you call `Save()` method on `Image` property and not on `pictureBox` instance.

```
WebCam camera = new WebCam();
camera.Connect();
Image image = camera.GetBitmap();
image.Save(@"c:\image1 " + ".Jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Gives me 6 errors. First on var, Second is "mismatch between processor architecture being built MSIL", Metricam.IProvidersBitmapOutPut is defined in assembly that is not referenced

Comment: But it works in winform? Describe your environment please. (OS, hardware, .net version, build target)

Comment: `defined in assembly that is not referenced` well, add reference to metricam dll. As of `var`, if you use older .net it will not work, i will update code to support older c#

Comment: somehow fixed it with your help. You made me confident to debug it :)

Comment: my OS is win8pro, Intel Core I7, .Net 4.50.

Comment: Meanwhile I also tried AForge Webcam, I found it a bit faster as compared to this MetriCam

Comment: I can't manage to edit my post. Its keep irking me on some errors "Looks like you have most of the code stuff" :D

Comment: You shouldn't edit question if you want to ask another one - just add it and send me the link here, i'll try to help.

Comment: Oh ok, would be careful next time